# Use local mirror of Alpine when build images of docker-compose instead legacy repositories

Tags: docker-compose, alpine-linux

Is it possible to use a local repository (mirror) that is used by docker when building a container with docker-compose?

I have a local mirror, and my interest is that when I build a container with docker-compose build, the apk is downloaded from the local mirror, instead of the Internet

Example.

If a local deploy with Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.13

# Install packages and remove default server definition
RUN apk --no-cache add php8=8.0.2-r0 php8-fpm php8-opcache php8-mysqli php8-json \
    php8-openssl php8-curl php8-soap php8-zlib php8-xml php8-phar php8-intl php8-dom php8-xmlreader php8-ctype \
    php8-session php8-simplexml php8-mbstring php8-gd nginx supervisor curl php8-exif php8-zip php8-fileinfo \
    php8-iconv php8-soap tzdata htop mysql-client php8-pecl-imagick php8-pecl-redis php8-tokenizer php8-xmlwriter \
    nano && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

When deploy container with `docker-compose build` I like that use my local repository of alpine instead any internet mirrors of Alpine such:

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/124) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r5)
(2/124) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r3)
(3/124) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.42.0-r1)
...
```

Answer (score 4):

After read alpine docs [Alpine Linux package management](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) I get solution using static IP of local mirror. I tried to use the name of the hostname (repoalpine.test) but I couldn't find how to make the hostname public on the docker network.

```
RUN apk --no-cache -X http://172.20.0.254/v3.13/main -X http://172.20.0.254/v3.13/community \
    add php8=8.0.2-r0 php8-fpm php8-opcache php8-mysqli php8-json \
    php8-openssl php8-curl php8-soap php8-zlib php8-xml php8-phar php8-intl php8-dom php8-xmlreader php8-ctype \
    php8-session php8-simplexml php8-mbstring php8-gd nginx supervisor curl php8-exif php8-zip php8-fileinfo \
    php8-iconv php8-soap tzdata htop mysql-client php8-pecl-imagick php8-pecl-redis php8-tokenizer php8-xmlwriter \
    nano && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now work

```
Step 7/22 : RUN apk --no-cache -X http://172.20.0.254/v3.13/main -X http://172.20.0.254/v3.13/community     add php8=8.0.2-r0 php8-fpm php8-opcache php8-mysqli php8-json     php8-openssl php8-curl php8-soap php8-zlib php8-xml php8-phar php8-intl php8-dom php8-xmlreader php8-ctype     php8-session php8-simplexml php8-mbstring php8-gd nginx supervisor curl php8-exif php8-zip php8-fileinfo     php8-iconv php8-soap tzdata htop mysql-client php8-pecl-imagick php8-pecl-redis php8-tokenizer php8-xmlwriter     nano && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 ---> Running in 4f2c6521e6e6
fetch http://172.20.0.254/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a local [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

Comment: My interest is not in doing docker pull, but rather when building an Alpine image with docker-compose build, if on Dockerfile has a RUN apk add somepackage docker-compose not call to Alpine's repositories. Instead call to my local repo.
Docker Regsitry is "The Registry is a stateless, highly scalable server side application that stores and lets you distribute Docker images"